# php, jquery problem : google chrome?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I am having a problem with Google Chrome.

I have a jQuery Registration form: http://www.topgamedb.com/register.php

When the form is filled out on Firefox, it works perfectly.

When the form is filled out on Chrome, it works perfectly - up until you submit (the page just refreshes).

I have tested my posts, and they work for other things, for example:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
echo "hello";
}
```

works fine, although if I use the $_POST['register'] one, the page just refreshes.

What could be causing it not to post on Chrome - for this specific post variable? but able to post on Firefox?

The script basically looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])){
    //do this
}else{
    //show form
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to put a value to your register button? (I guess it is submitted but is empty) Try something like

```
<button onclick="return registration.submitValidate();" class="btn" name="register" value="here_is_my_value" type="submit" style="opacity: 1;"><span>Register</span></button>
```

I hope it works this way

Comment: If you just output the $_POST array it says about $_POST['register'] ??? Does it exist?   If i understand what you are trying to do, if you have $_POST['register']) you do something else you show the form again.   So it seems that the code goes to else branch. Complete your form and submite it then show us what is $_POST (put print_r($_POST) before the if clause

Comment: I don't think its anything to do with the PHP.. if I remove the registration.js from the page, and try and submit the form without the jquery, it submits fine..

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the button the id of register as well (is this still needed) as the name.

Comment: It has to be something in the js.. its all I can think of.